# How do I use Lawnchair with more than one table?

Tags: javascript, lawnchair

I am trying to use Lawnchair (http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) for a mobile project to store information about different things. I need to store in more than more table.

```
var people = new Lawnchair('people');

var groups = new Lawnchair('groups');
```

This does not completely work, it tries to copy contents from the people table to the group table. I have tried setting people.adapter.table on the fly which also results in a similar issue. I'm beginning to think it is not possible to have more than one table with Lawnchair..

Any help?

Comment: put the tables together and place the lawnchair in the middle.  don't forget to wear sunscreen.

Answer (score 8):

You should set the 'name' option on your Lawnchair instances:

```
var people = new Lawnchair({name: "people"}, function(){});

var groups = new Lawnchair({name: "groups"}, function(){});
```

-Marc

Answer (score 1):

try older Lawnchair
[JavaScript Lawnchair library.. stored as same "table"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944265/javascript-lawnchair-library-stored-as-same-table)

Comment: dident mean to down vote this, but cannot work out how to cancel the down vote, so up vote it is i guess...

Comment: @nodrog Just click on the arrow you clicked the first time.

Comment: This should really be a comment, unless you say why the older Lawnchair works and not the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Lawnchair, but it appears to be serializing your objects to JSON which doesn't support references. You might need to convert your objects to some intermediate form (i.e. replace the "people" reference with its key. Then, after you read it, you could use the key to get the object back.

Answer (score 0):

Lawnchair is a cross mobile device key-value data store that insulates you from worrying about what platform your code is on.

You are trying to bend LawnChair in to doing something that it isn't designed to do.

You need to do full HTML5 database SQL.

Answer (score 0):

And also be noted that, use adapter as 'dom' if you have no specific adaptor,  sometimes Lawnchair will use window-name adapter as default adaptor, which have some problems with multiple table scenario.